# How to add Bootstrap icons in Sitecore MVC link fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore8

I have below HTML Code:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

Using Sitecore MVC Field:

```
 @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })
 @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
 @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Result:

```
<a href="/en" data_toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites</a> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
```

Expected Result:

```
<a href="/en" data_toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

Please help me , How I can I integrate Bootstrap icons into Sitecore fields.

Comment: What is `Link Field` and `Destination URL` fields? Are they both General Link fields? If so, why do you have 2 link fields nested?

Comment: public class BrandNavigaion
    {
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Destination URL",FieldType=SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
My model like this        public virtual Link DestinationURL { get; set; }
        [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Is Active ", FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.Checkbox)]
        public virtual bool IsActive  { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Updated Code:
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Destination URL")
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })
<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the following:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Destination URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" })
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
@Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<a href="/my-url" data_toggle="dropdown">My Page Name
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

Since you are clearly using Glass Mapper in your solution then you should make use of this functionality instead of using the Sitecore Field helpers and "magic strings"

```
@Html.Glass().Editable(Model, x => x.DestinationURL, 
    string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">{1}<i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\"></i></a>", x.DestinationURL.Url, x.DestinationURL.Text))
```

Comment: Great, thank u,
out put coming like this,
<a href="/en" data_toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites11 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
Can we romove href, because of this I unable to get the sub links of under this, if click this link redirecting.

Comment: Or else can we disable the href property

Comment: @SureshR Updated the answer with Glass specific example, using which you can control the output HTML.

Comment: using glass mapper, am getting error -  'x' is inaccessible due to its protection level, here I changed from x to i,j,m..etc, is there any namespace to would be add ?

Comment: @SureshR Depends on how you have your models referenced on the page. Try changing `Model` to `item` instead in this case.

Comment: @Editable(item, x => x.DestinationURL, string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">{1}<i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\"></i></a>", x.DestinationURL.Url, x.DestinationURL.Text))

Comment: I am new to site core, Please update  jammykam, above code actually am using  help of glass mapper, I used item in place of model, still am getting error.

Comment: I'd need to see the relevant parts of the code for your model and view (include the `@using` and `@inherits` statements), please update your original question with these details, it makes the formatting easier than the comment box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107141/discussion-between-suresh-r-and-jammykam).